# What HTTP Server should I use with python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm trying to set up a HTTP sever on Google Cloud. I've run this with python and flask with no problems at all. When I go to the cloud console, create the app and deploy, with pure python and flask, an error occurs. Meanwhile, I tried using gunicorn but I get the same type of error.

My main.py file:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return jsonify({"about": "Hello World"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

APP.YAML

```
env: flex
runtime: python
runtime_config: 
  pythom_version: 3
```

I expect to receive a string in JSON format like the following:

```
{
  "about": "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Dustin's comment plus include your requirements.txt file which should have at a minimum the line "Flask==1.0.3". Also, add your `gcloud app deploy` command.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typo: `pythom_version`, it should be: `python_version`.